# Limit Meteor Vote Once Per Day

Tags: javascript, meteor, ip, leaderboard, vote

I'm following the MeteorJS example for a leaderboard here: https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard

I want to limit the votes to once per day (per IP address). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Create a Meteor method for upvotes. In the Method you can access the ip of the voter by this.connection.clientAddresshttp://docs.meteor.com/#method_connection

Comment: @imslavko Can you please give me some source code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution assumes you are starting with a clean version of the leaderboard example.

Step one: Declare a new collection to hold IP address and date information. This can be added just below the definition of `Players`.

```
IPs = new Meteor.Collection('ips');
```

Step two: Replace the increment event with a call to our new method `givePoints`.

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
  'click input.inc': function() {
    var playerId = Session.get('selected_player');
    Meteor.call('givePoints', playerId, function(err) {
      if (err)
        alert(err.reason);
    });
  }
});
```

Step three: Define the `givePoints` method on the server (`this.connection` only works on the server). You can do this by inserting the following anywhere inside of the `Meteor.isServer` check or by creating a new file under the `/server` directory.

```
Meteor.methods({
  givePoints: function(playerId) {
    check(playerId, String);

    // we want to use a date with a 1-day granularity
    var startOfDay = new Date;
    startOfDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // the IP address of the caller
    ip = this.connection.clientAddress;

    // check by ip and date (these should be indexed)
    if (IPs.findOne({ip: ip, date: startOfDay})) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'You already voted!');
    } else {
      // the player has not voted yet
      Players.update(playerId, {$inc: {score: 5}});

      // make sure she cannot vote again today
      IPs.insert({ip: ip, date: startOfDay});
    }
  }
});
```

The complete code can be seen in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dweldon/cbe355b622d54df775a2).

Comment: Everything looks good, but for some reason it's not working. Am I supposed to put step three in the `Meteor.isServer` function? I'm getting no errors. I've tried putting in before, in, and after that function. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah you want to put it under the `Meteor.isServer` check, or put it in a new file anywhere in the `/server` directory. I modified the answer to be more clear. I can create a gist if this still isn't working for you.

Comment: Would you mind creating a gist? Don't understand why it's not working. Thanks so much.

Comment: Okay I added the gist at the end of the answer. So if you check out a clean leaderboard project and replace `leaderboard.js` with the above, it should work. When running locally the expected experience would be that you can vote for one person, and then not again until the next day (there isn't any visual feedback apart from the 2nd vote not changing the score).

Comment: Is there a way to display an error message? Can I just change out the 403 message with `console.log("ERROR")`?

Comment: Sure - I updated the code with an example. It the method received an error from the server it will alert the user.